# HTML in Markdown - Table caption and Entire thead Showing as All One Row

Tags: html, html-table, markdown

I am making a Markdown file in which I want to include some tables. I figured that the way to do this would be to use an HTML table inside my Markdown. I have made a lot of HTML tables before and never had a problem with them, however the following problem occurs with every markdown implementation I have tried - JetBrains Markdown Plugin, StackExchange, and GFM on GitHub.

I want to make a table titled "Menu" with a list of dishes that go in a menu. My HTML for the table is...

```
<table>
    <caption>Menu</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Dish 1</th>
            <th>Dish 2</th>
            <th>Dish 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- the table body is not relevant to this post -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that when I put this in Markdown it looks like this. ***Note:*** I am inputting this directly into the StackExchange Markdown engine, it is not copied from elsewhere.

---

Menu
    
         
            Dish 1
            Dish 2
            Dish 3

---

This is very strange and I don't know why it's happening. When I use the exact same code in an HTML body tag I get the correct output. This image was captured from a rendering in a Chrome browser.

[image: My HTML displayed in a Chrome browser]

So why is this happening? Are tables just not supported in Markdown? Or am I supposed to be doing something differently?

Answer (score 0):

If you "view source" your post, the HTML output looks like this:

```
<hr>


    Menu


            Dish 1
            Dish 2
            Dish 3







<hr>
```

What is interesting is all of the blank lines. It would appear that all of the HTML tags have been stripped out, leaving only the text (including whitespace). Of course, as whitespace is collapsed by browsers, you are seeing all of the text on one line.

In [standard Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html), the HTML would be passed through unchanged. However, when a site allows untrusted users to insert arbitrary HTML into there site, that presents a security issue such as [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Therefore, sites like StackExcange and Github will strip out the RAW HTML as a security measure. That doesn't mean you can't use any raw HTML, but only a limited whitelist. For example, StachExchange has documented their whitelist [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909). From a review of that list it is clear that tables in raw HTML are not an option on StackExchange. And a review of their [Markdown support](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) indicates that Markdown based tables are not supported either. It would appear that tables of any kind are disallowed by StackExchange. You may need to find a different way to format your data.